# yii2 change database for admin and site panel

Tags: yii2

I have the following config file

common/main-local.php

```
 return [
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=aishwariya_basic2',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    // 'db' => $db,
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=aishwariya_basic',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        ],
            // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=> [
        'class' => 'yii2-widget-linkpager',
        'application.extensions.MyLinkPager.*',

],
  ],
];
```

Admincontroller

```
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use frontend\models\Site_login;
use frontend\models\EntryForm_model;
use frontend\models\Asal_page_model;
use frontend\models\Interest_page_model;
use frontend\models\Return_page_model;
use frontend\models\Daily_report_model;
use frontend\models\Changepassword;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\db\Query;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' =>  [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['index', 'signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['settings','changepassword'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],





            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

#####Action index code starts here 

public function actionIndex()
    {

        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $my2DbConn = Yii::$app->db;

        $model = new Site_login();


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) 
            {

                if ($model->validate()) {
            $url = Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl()."/admin/search";
              return $this->redirect($url);
                                        } 
           }
        return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model]);
    }
```

Site controller

```
public function actionInitial()
{
    $this->layout = 'site'; 
    $my2DbConn = Yii::$app->db2;        
    $model=new Initial_model();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
    }
return $this->render('initial',['model'=>$model]);
    }
```

I would like to change the database belongs to controller. Please give me some help. I have used two db but it tooks first db file.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure  more then a db in config

```
return [
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb',
        'username' => 'demo',
        'password' => 'demo',
    ],
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb2',
        'username' => 'demo2',
        'password' => 'demo2',
    ],
  ],
];
```

and obtain your db (this is if you want use direct command in controller and not for activeRecord)

```
class yourController extends \yii\web\Controller
{


   public function actionYourAction()
   {
      ...

     $my2DbConn = Yii::$app->db2;

      ....

   }
```

Or you can manage programmatically with the proper setting

If for your model (like you have in your code ) you want to use a different database connection other than the db component, you should override the getDb() method in your related ActiveRecord MODEL (see the doc .. link at the bottom):

```
class YourModel extends ActiveRecord  // eg: Initial_model
{
   // ...

   public static function getDb()
   {
      // use the "db2" application component
      return \Yii::$app->db2;  
   }
}
```

and not assign   `$my2DbConn = Yii::$app->db;`  in controller  this is for createCommand (direct sql commend)  and not for activeRecord like you need ..

see this guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html or this reference for related param http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html

Comment: We should specify $my2dbConn in every action ?

Comment: You can do  at the leve you perfer ... in controller too if you use in all the actions or only in the action you need ..you can do too in model and then use a function for get the db of the model ..like in the guide ..

Comment: what mean not working ... error .. wrong result .. update your post with the code you are using and explain your goal .. please

Comment: I have configured more than one db in config file . and accessed via $my2DbConn = Yii::$app->db2; in every action . But it will took the same first db file . not going through second db2 file

Comment: show your db and db2 config code .. and an action where you use them.. (update your question with the related code ..) so ai can check

Comment: Edited my post. please check

Comment: You are using activeRecoed    then you should redefine the getDb method in model .. but lookin at your code you never accessing to db  .. you just create new model in function but don't perform .. save o query to your db .. so i thing you should study a deep more how do this  ...and not change db.... i have anyway update the asnwer for the question